# Error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[25]’ from type ‘char *’

Tags: c

I'm trying to assign the values of a struct to a map but the following error message appears after compiling:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[25]’ from type ‘char *’
```

in

```
map[i].n=m.n
```

My struct is defined this way:

```
struct m1{
int c;
char n[25];
int q_m;
int q;};
```

Part of my code:

```
    struct m1 m;
    struct m1 *map = 0;
    scanf("%d",&m.c);
    scanf("%s",&m.n);
    scanf("%d",&m.q_m);
    scanf("%d",&m.q);

    map[i].c=m.c;
    map[i].n=m.n;
    map[i].q_m=m.q_m;
    map[i].q=m.q;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Array expressions may not be the target of an assignment; the `=` operator isn't defined to copy the *contents* of one array to the other.

If `n` is meant to hold a 0-terminated string, use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy( map[i].n, m.n );
```

If `n` is meant to hold a non-0-terminated string (or a sequence of characters with embedded 0 values), use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy( map[i].n, m.n, sizeof map[i].n );
```

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.

That's why you got the error message you did; the expression `m.n` has type "25-element array of `char`"; since it wasn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it was converted to type `char *`.  `map[i].n` wasn't converted (it stayed type `char [25]`), but as I said earlier, array expressions may not be the target of the assignment operator.

Comment: @CoolGuy: Yup.  I was addressing the specific error in the question, but yeah, `scanf("%s",&m.n);` needs to be `scanf("%s", m.n);`.

Answer (score 3):

Array variables cannot be an *lvalue* to the assignment operator, that is they cannot be assigned anything.

To copy an array, copy element by element or use a "low-level" function like [`memcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) to copy a specific amount of memory at once:

```
memcpy(map[i].n, m.n, sizeof map[i].n);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to allocate memory for `map`.

```
struct m1 *map = malloc(sizeof(struct m1));
```

and use `strcpy`to copy `m.n` to `map->n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct m1 *map;
```

`map` is a pointer and you should be allocating memory to it before writing something to it.

```
map = malloc(sizeof(struct m1) * n);
```

Then you can have

```
map[i]
```

After this fix string copy

```
strcpy(map[i].n,m.n);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you most likely want to do (besides allocating memory for the struct) is copying the contents of the array pointed to by `n`, instead of only copying the actual pointer.

```
strcpy(map[i].n, m.n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to assign directly m.n  value to the array.
Please see below detail Example :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct db{
    int db_num;
    char db_name[10];
};

int main()
{
    struct db *ptr;
    ptr = (struct db*)malloc(sizeof(struct db));
    ptr->db_num = 10;
    ptr->db_name = "xyz";
    printf("Input data Base:\n");
    printf("db_num:%d db_name:%s",ptr->db_num,(char*)ptr->db_name);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code snippet I am trying to assign "XYZ" to the array which is the member of struct db.
It through the similar Error because of ptr->db_name = "xyz";

st_dyna_mem.c:14: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[10]’ from type ‘char *’

Fix :
For Fixing this type of issue you Can use strcpy() or memcpy().
EX:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct db{
    int db_num;
    char db_name[10];
};

int main()
{
    struct db *ptr;
    ptr = (struct db*)malloc(sizeof(struct db));
    ptr->db_num = 10;
    strcpy(ptr->db_name,"xyz");
    printf("Input data Base:\n");
    printf("db_num:%d db_name:%s",ptr->db_num,(char*)ptr->db_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
db_num:10 db_name:xyz

Answer (score 0):

You copy all of the structure members. The simplest way to do that is:

```
map[i]=m;
```